# spark approach for running very small jobs

Tags: apache-spark, memory

We have 350 small tables and each with  with less than 100 records .50 large tables and each with 300 million records (20GB ORC size).
we are passing 1 executor + 1 core, 1g executor memory and 1g driver memory for all small tables. Large tables with   10 executors + 10 cores , 50g executor memory and 2g driver memory. 
While running a batch with load balanced way total batch time is getting more and memory consumption is also peak for the complete batch window . Memory usage graph shows rectangular one.

Please advise me how to handle this situation to give very less memory for very small tables with less than 100 records. each One Big tables is placed for every 10 small tables while submitting from oozie and batch is taking 3 hours ( cluster capacity 6 nodes- each with 128 core and total 1.35TB memory) with several changes in the ordering.
Please advise the idle way to ask for less memory in the batch and reduce time from 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I made the experience that cluster resources are more efficiently used if parallel jobs (i.e. parallel in the driver code) are launched for small tables. In Scala, this can look something like this:

```
// define transformations as (srcTable,targetTable and a transformation function which 
// reads the srcTable and saves the output in the targetTable
val transformations : Seq[(String,String, (String,String) => Unit)] = ???

val batchsize : Int  = ???

transformations
  .grouped(batchsize)
  .foreach(batch => batch.par // parallel job launches!
    .foreach{case (srcTable,tgtTable,transformation) => transformation(srcTable,tgtTable)}
  )
```